# Python - list of tuples from file

Tags: python, list, file, tuples, loading

I have completed some rather intensive calculations, and i was not able to save my results in pickle (recursion depth exceded), so i was forced to print all the data and save it in a text file.

Is there any easy way to now convert my list of tuples in text to well... list of tuples in python? the output looks like this:

```
[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 5), (14, 5), (103360, 7), (16, 6), (102725, 7), (17, 6), (18, 5), (19, 9), (20, 6), ...(it continues for 60MB)]
```

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python

Comment: Wait, that data is quite flat. Why would pickle exceed recursion depth for this? Is that data example really representative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> s = '[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 5), (14, 5)]'
>>> res = ast.literal_eval(s)
[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 5), (14, 5)]
>>> res[0]
(10, 5)
```

Comment: i would have to include the whole data in my source then, no?

Comment: @KONAKONA No, you'd read it from whatever file it's been saved to

Comment: @KONAKONA Do you mean that you want to convert only a subset of your stored data?

Comment: Alright, since it is all in one line, i can just read that line, convert it to string, and use ast.literal_eval(), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 5), (14, 5), (103360, 7), (16, 6), (102725, 7), (17, 6), (18, 5), (19, 9), (20, 6)]" # Read it from the file however you want

values = []
for t in string[1:-1].replace("),", ");").split("; "):
    values.append(tuple(map(int, t[1:-1].split(", "))))
```

First I remove the start and end square bracket with `[1:-1]`, I replace `),` with `);` to be able to split by `;` so that the it foesn't split by the commas inside the tuples as they are not preceded by a `)`. Inside the loop I'm using `[1:-1]` to remove the parenthesis this time and splitting by the commas. The `map` part is to convert the numeric `str`s into `int`s and I'm appending them as a `tuple`.